# Inter Document Similarity: Cosine distance

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, nlp, nltk, scikit-learn

**Updated Question:**

According to **"perimosocordiae"** s solution I found out the cosine similarity between 2 documents. I have tried to use the solution to find out similarity between 2 Files. But again an error arises in test(), which is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3.py", line 103, in <module>
    main()
  File "3.py", line 99, in main
    test(tf_idf_matrix,count,nltkutil.cosine_distance)
  File "3.py", line 46, in test
    doc2 = np.asarray(tdMatrix[j-1].todense()).reshape(-1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 281, in __getitem__
    return self[key,:]                                #[i] or [1:2]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 233, in __getitem__
    return self._get_row_slice(row, col)      #[i,1:2]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 320, in _get_row_slice
    raise IndexError('index (%d) out of range' % i )
IndexError: index (4) out of range
```

I am using one file as the train set and the other file as test set and my objective is to use the `test()` function to output the cosine similarity between 2 files using tf-idf.

My code is the following:

```
#! /usr/bin/python -tt
from __future__ import division
from operator import itemgetter

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
import nltk.cluster.util as nltkutil
import numpy as np
import re

def preprocess(fnin, fnout):
    fin = open(fnin, 'rb')
    print fin
    fout = open(fnout, 'wb')
    buf = []

    for line in fin:

        line = line.strip()
        if line.find("-- Document Separator --") > -1:
            if len(buf) > 0:

                    body = re.sub("\s+", " ", " ".join(buf))
                    fout.write("%s\n" % (body))

                rest = map(lambda x: x.strip(), line.split(": "))

                buf = []
            else:
                buf.append(line)

    fin.close()
    fout.close()

def test(tdMatrix,count,fsim):

    sims=[] 

    sims = np.zeros((len(tdMatrix.todense()), count))
    l=len(tdMatrix.todense())

    for i in range(0, l):
        for j in range(0, count):
                doc1 = np.asarray(tdMatrix[i].todense()).reshape(-1)
                doc2 = np.asarray(tdMatrix[j].todense()).reshape(-1)

                sims[i, j] = fsim(doc1, doc2)

        print sims


def main():

    file_set=["corpusA.txt","corpusB.txt"]
    train=[]
    test1=[]

    for file1 in file_set:
        s="x"+file1
        preprocess(file1,s)

    count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
    m=open("xcorpusA.txt",'r')
    for i in m:
        train.append(i.strip())
    #print doc
    #print train
    count_vectorizer.fit_transform(train)
    #print "Vocabulary:", count_vectorizer.vocabulary

    # Vocabulary: {'blue': 0, 'sun': 1, 'bright': 2, 'sky': 3}

    m1=open("xcorpusB.txt",'r')
    for i in m1:
        test1.append(i.strip())

    freq_term_matrix = count_vectorizer.transform(test1)
    #print freq_term_matrix.todense()

    tfidf = TfidfTransformer(norm="l2")
    tfidf.fit(freq_term_matrix)

    #print "IDF:", tfidf.idf_

    tf_idf_matrix = tfidf.transform(freq_term_matrix)
    print (tf_idf_matrix.toarray())

    count=0
    s=""
    for i in tf_idf_matrix.toarray():
        for j in i:
            count+=1    
        break

    #print count
    #print type(tf_idf_matrix)
    print "Results with Cosine Distance Similarity Measure"
    test(tf_idf_matrix,count,nltkutil.cosine_distance)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am looking for any advice from respective mentors.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in this expression:

```
tdMatrix[tdMatrix[i], :]
```

Your `tdMatrix` is a 2x2 array of floating point numbers, and indexing itself is going to fail. Perhaps you meant:

```
doc1 = np.asarray(tdMatrix[i].todense()).reshape(-1)
```

Comment: Thank You. After following your suggestion, no error is displayed. and the cosine simialrity appears [[1. 0.81818021] [.81818021 1.]]. I am not sure whether it is correct or not. Because frequency term matrix appears here as :[[1 2] [0 2]] But it should appear as [[0 1 1 1][0 2 1 0]]. Can you advice me any suggestion?